# Contador javascript para controller php

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados

Tenho um formulário com inputs dinamicos:

```
<form method="post" action="getDatabases/getCurso.php">                                            
                                    <div class="field_wrapper_curso">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 contentCurso">
                                            <div class="col-xs-4">                                                         
                                                <div class="form-group">

                                            <div class="col-xs-4">                                                         
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Curso</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_curso_curso[]" value=""/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-2">                                                         
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Conclusão</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="field_curso_conclusao">
                                                        <option></option>
                                                        <option>Concluido em:</option>
                                                        <option>Espero concluir em:</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-1">                                                         
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Ano</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Ano" name="field_curso_ano[]" value=""/>
                                                </div>   
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                                <p><br></p>
                                                <a href="javascript:newCurso(void(0));" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove_curso_button hide" title="Remove field"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>  <!--/.field_wrapper_curso -->

                                        <input type="submit"/> 
                                    </form>  <!--/ formulario curso -->
```

A parte dinâmica é montada pelo js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
        // Adicionar Cursos
        $(document).ready(function newCurso() {
            var maxFieldCurso = 50; //Input fields increment limitation
            var addButtonCurso = $('.add_curso_button'); //Add button selector
            var wrapperCurso = $('.field_wrapper_curso'); //Input field wrapper
            var contCurso = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

            $(addButtonCurso).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
                if(contCurso < maxFieldCurso){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                    console.log("aaa")
                    contCurso++; //Increment field counter
                    $('.contentCurso:last').clone().appendTo(wrapperCurso); // Add field html
                }
                if($('.contentCurso').length != 1) {
                  $('.remove_curso_button').removeClass('hide');
                }
            });
            $(wrapperCurso).on('click', '.remove_curso_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //Remove field html
                contCurso--; //Decrement field counter
                if($('.contentCurso').length == 1) {
                  $('.remove_curso_button').addClass('hide');
                }
            });   

    </script>
```

Agora preciso montar um controller em php que pegue esses dados, como estou utilizando uma array em cada campo, estou fazendo assim:

```
    $instituicao = $_POST['field_curso_instituicao'];
    $curso = $_POST['field_curso_curso'];
    $conclusao = $_POST['field_curso_conclusao'];
    $ano = $_POST['field_curso_ano'];
```

mas preciso criar um laço de `for` para correr esses dados e armazenar no BD, e quero usar o contador `contCurso` da função js para o mesmo

De modo grosseiro, seria algo parecido com isso :

```
$queryBD = "insert into bd(instituicao,curso,conclusao,ano) values ("$instituicao","$curso","$conclusao","$ano")"

    for($i=0; $i= $contCurso; $i++){
      $queryBD;
}
```

O que eu quero saber é o seguinte: De que maneira posso passar o valor da variável de contador `contCurso` (javascript) para um laço de for em um controller separado em php?

Obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode só incluir o valor do contador em um campo escondido e usar isso, não?

```
<input type="hidden" id="inputContador" name="contador">
```

Aí ao invés de só aumentar a variável, você usa uma função pra aumentar o valor do contador já presente na página:

```js
var addContador = function(){
    var acc = parseInt( $('#inputContador').val(), 10);
    console.log(acc);
    acc += 1;
    $('#inputContador').val(acc);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="contador" id="inputContador" value="0" />

<button onclick="addContador()">+1</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou, agradeço, só uma pergunta: pra que serve o 10 em  var acc = parseInt( $('#inputContador').val(), 10); ??

Comment: é o segundo argumento da função ``parseInt()``, o primeiro é a string para converter em número e o segundo argumento é a base numérica usada (normalmente nem se coloca, mas eu sou paranóico do Javascript achar que o número é um octal, por exemplo).

Comment: legal, agradeço muito